# Robert Cartaino's profile is linked with "moderator on 3 other sites" on the Area 51 page

Tags: support, bug, area-51, moderators

On the [Bioinformatics Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics), I saw [Robert Cartaino's](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino?tab=accounts) profile in the "edited by" section. In his profile I saw that he is "moderator on 3 other sites", so I have searched on the [Stack Exchange Moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) page for his name, but I didn't see that he is moderator on any of the Stack Exchange site now.

So, is the moderator icon on his Area 51 profile a bug (not updated)? Or are there any other reasons behind that?

**Bioinformatics Area 51 page:**

> [image: Bioinformatics]

**Moderators page:**

> [image: Moderators]

Comment: Looks like the number never drops, but rather increase by 1 whenever the user gets a new diamond somewhere (or several diamonds in same time).

Comment: Also reported on Area 51's meta: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31264/robert-cartainos-flair-says-hes-a-moderator-on-3-other-sites-but-he-isnt (I left a comment there explaining why it happens.)